# Print text vertically

Tags: c#, printing

I've a Cheque and I'm trying to print its data manually - report tools aren't permitted - and my target is a PDF printer and Cheque paper and I must use an A4 printer.

Here is an illustration:

[image]

My steps are:

1. Specify cheque size as my actual paper size.
2. write the data.
3. Print result to the printer.

In step 1, I've created `PrintDocument` instance and set `DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize` to match the input paper dimensions by setting `RawKind` to `120` which means custom paper size, then I setup a `PrintPage` handler, Then I call `Print`.

In Step 2, that data written to the `e.Graphics` without problem.

In Step 3, when print to a PDF printer the result is as expected, and the strings can be copied, also the manual preview on a a cheque image is good.

The problem when I print to the A4 printer - HP Laserjet 1018 - I set the ruler of upper paper tray to the middle so it can hold the cheque which I put **vertically**, Now when printing two thing happened:

1. the text printed horizontally.
2. because printer ruler is set to the middle, the print location is invalid (or i think so, i didn't actually get the chance to test that result).

How can I fix the printer problems?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: got it, won't forget it again, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        float vlblControlWidth;
        float vlblControlHeight;
        float vlblTransformX;
        float vlblTransformY;

        Color controlBackColor = BackColor;
        Pen labelBorderPen;
        SolidBrush labelBackColorBrush;

        if (_transparentBG)
        {
            labelBorderPen = new Pen(Color.Empty, 0);
            labelBackColorBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Empty);
            }
            else
            {
               labelBorderPen = new Pen(controlBackColor, 0);
              labelBackColorBrush = new SolidBrush(controlBackColor);
          }

        SolidBrush labelForeColorBrush = new SolidBrush(base.ForeColor);
        base.OnPaint(e);
        vlblControlWidth = this.Size.Width;
        vlblControlHeight = this.Size.Height;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(labelBorderPen, 0, 0, 
                                 vlblControlWidth, vlblControlHeight);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(labelBackColorBrush, 0, 0, 
                                 vlblControlWidth, vlblControlHeight);
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = this._renderMode;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = 
                   System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        if (this.TextDrawMode == DrawMode.BottomUp)
        {
            vlblTransformX = 0;
            vlblTransformY = vlblControlHeight;
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(vlblTransformX, vlblTransformY);
            e.Graphics.RotateTransform(270);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(labelText, Font, labelForeColorBrush, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
                 vlblTransformX = vlblControlWidth;
                 vlblTransformY = vlblControlHeight;
                 e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(vlblControlWidth, 0);
                 e.Graphics.RotateTransform(90);
                 e.Graphics.DrawString(labelText, Font, labelForeColorBrush, 0,
                                     0,StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            }            
        }

        SetStyle(System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.Opaque, true);

  }

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;  // Turn on WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        return cp;
    }
}
```